# Customize Calendar

Tags: calendar, customization

Are there possible ways to customize calendar in Saleforce? For example, i want to "get" the event when user changes view from Day to Week for example. Or is there an easy way to create a calendar lightning component from scratch ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to your question is no. Standard calendar is a pain to do anything with.

You may have more luck with a custom component - e.g.
https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs

Comment: Hi TLY and thanks for your suggestion. I try to use this component but when i try to deploy it from vs code i get an error message: Invalid reference FullCalendarJS of type resourceUrl in file fullCalendarJs.js   I have inserted in my orgs static resources the .zip file as well as i have put in my force-app\main\default\lwc\staticresources this zip file.... What am i doing wrong ?